# Odd files in the /tmp directory?

Tags: linux, centos

Wasn't able to find this here, but i have an odd issue, i found several files in the /tmp directory of my Centos web server named like.

```
php2qUuKs
php2v8kJc
php7XD6ku
php0652pa
```

And they all have content like:

```
ˇÿˇ‡JFIF¥¥ˇ· ‚ExifII*
™∞«œ(1◊2Ú>?Fiá`XCanonCanon EOS 300D DIGITAL¥¥Adobe Photoshop CS Windows2004:10:26 19:12:519ËIË@d!ddGddd+ËKËrËöÇŒùÇ÷'àêê0221êﬁêÚëëí
íí
í&í   í
í.Üí6†0100†††¢>¢F¢¢£§§§§•N2Z
2004:10:17 15:59:212004:10:17 15:59:21‘§W‘§'‡.|@S
¶Æ(∂$HHˇÿˇ‡JFIFHHˇÌAdobe_CMˇÓAdobedÄˇ€Ñ         



ˇ¿x†"ˇ›
ˇƒ?  
 
3!1AQa"qÅ2ë°±B#$R¡b34rÇ—C%íS·Òcs5¢≤É&DìTdE¬£t6“U‚eÚ≥Ñ√”u„ÛF'î§Ö¥ïƒ‘‰Ù•µ≈’ÂıVfvÜñ¶∂∆÷Êˆ7GWgwáóß∑«◊Á˜5!1AQaq"2Åë°±B#¡R—3$b·rÇíCScs4Ò%¢≤É&5¬“DìT£dEU6te‚Ú≥Ñ√”u„ÛFî§Ö¥ïƒ‘‰Ù•µ≈’ÂıVfvÜñ¶∂∆÷Êˆ'7GWgwáóß∑«ˇ⁄?ÿ≥¨2Ê}VWIUSQJDR
_@BB  VVC]
ZKJB^[QB\WAoMXY\@ZXY
F
IG]^   LY@C[BAT]SA\KFWX_TFDUtVV]__
QRTR
DI
DBZ[Y@TZGH\   
BKVW]V_pUNWKJKVPENAHKQ^_S@\D]@@CPK0^VXXED]RCURUMCBRIQ
E(
ZCKH\\XZ_QUJ]SQIQUMQ^I[_TL@
P\nCH
QG[VMTRSDC_
]JYIJN
][&

@Z^^

J

RBSX\@RWIETU
[3VUQ^\UVZDQEQY[ZKZDYVX[FD#NZ]T_LWTUFJwLQX@KMUJFRRBV@AP_KKWZ]G
JZU]\AXB@)QVA^NZNRYKU
S@IPUIR\VDQ.@TO^QOU_I
RY\GKPK    VUC
B_Q\@PAC,

BDR_B  UUQT@QRT
R

G]&CZ^^

J

]QYYXL]GRWIG[UXJNFRX]HTVX@FYRCU])XPB^NZNRYKTAWTDQ
Z\KD]!
AG@KWILPV   ULE@KTJJG<_[GoFXR\BDBYYXL@^@NZNRWKBJt^\RFZT[BC
E_QD
_]\FXAF^BAVMIQSNFWNX_C_XZGppX@A
VTKJAZ[QTQEPZ
]GPE
TDE]   /  TXGFCHY^SQ]YWDRK]T
F
IG!
ZQ\   Z[nG    BBB    QUNPBD
ZX_KJB^[QL
pR\XQCoMXY\@ZXY
F
IGF@XXW   _^IGTWBAT]SB\K[QKyV[CV_]
HIB_ULXG@BUDTW]G
]VWASP@@XJT\FYRXpHGTRAFVCKDU@JR_
N\

Z\CCp
XUB/    3
A]L  N^NRZWQPQK\KB
MUJIRR_3V
]L[T\
T  EWA]V]
GJKVSBNAA
C]VKt@P[@YT[BC
E_Q[[ZKI_ACZTFMMI^SN@[]R\Av^ZUF[S_BQ^IXYTPI\Y[
ZFJDR_ABR@RVXNUTCIo
A
VTKJAZ[Q@W^\ALXSLRE_UXN.^TO^QOU_I
_U]P]UZSC
C_QRPZBYD0AM
]_B_N
OF
CGWIQK-UUGH#VCSLC3F@Qq_@@\_][DS_BMGHS^UJFRRR(Oc[Q]XRASfZU[C]UG\3    MJNNZY]KDDR_@U
[I^QJ@XBW_\M]ZCD    PK]
]VWI
XMFG\
HIFZ\\RkOWWyTZ[OMFMOTK   I%LIR]MYWR[K S
KJJI%ENZMG@QVBJF_]JSITWP
CG;Ff[NBS[NZECSN^\ZP
;FF
@^FQVCNFUHVSNnQOPAC
ENZWPHSMG@ZP^N
SUR8
    P  C SNI
EJF@[@DWNH^G\$

OVLLTCS@ZgQ@@XS\C~GYCEIV\XP    SZIJF;JXU^[^\EQVQ^

S
ICHLBSBILWAX]KSJ^FJD
LyIT\ZLCAKF@VG@CZ_HfQUCFSOXOKP  AO@GH-[[PQJPDCXZ[YAEOJF    H;OOYCI
XPZVBV@N[^D@SS
LM
O)
BOgINLBQFV[M_]AP^UJSN[\
HLXExX_J_[XBJ       OUUP   T
VIN
JGExAS\S[XI_ZSSJA
T

JGEr\BSVZKXQ[JS
S\J@=CCI@   RVCNZB@JFUH
-VTKPPS]S@I    NGLCVDPP\[[_GS:E
NSL]HC^IAI%EBU^\D_WPIXGQ
NPW]+
WHSfFE\VC]V^^FC[UUKSO \ML    O]I;AUVV[XY@TPQ^S
JL\W9é·ÍCANF@P\FPY[MXQII3IMA:TXS\    FZ^DJBVZKBQHVSILEgPAJF[X_WOVBFTZS[S;_S
N@V[PACOS^APRXFSKw@ZPQAENT\LCAS'I
AM}R[_WVL_\S[OVIPL  OJK    I
FSQEOfPN[ZAUH[SS
R\LC&C
I
X@^FAQV@NZEXIR\PeUOMWY]
SAK3LHUGM[OPEp
LS\KFSX\V[NEW’¥∂CXQKSS
_nPSCAbQP]KTNMRFDI
OVLBHSO]DFSLtZZOfNVZ[TRFE^[  H    T
YHaEG\IFXZMXSVYL:ãÔ˜JK
C\AI
SHQM@@[\GJOV_]S O\\JP    P
OJTP]Sw_[]YL}f?#S

JA
P

VI
SHQM_N_]K}VXW@S
RWP
SJF
JWXTGBEn[ZBY\CSS
\ZHT
JMVDKSJ^FJA_L{
SNJU[P    TOIKF
S}FZCZZUDRI_ZSS
V@P  P@,SXUWE[YDCN[Y_G

IKT

(SZI
@I
SJUM^VIBG\NC\@  
$N^VOHLTESV   LKHp”≥∂@\ZJAPBMS/
R\JPC
AFSH]OTBSVIVC_BS_PBH L:LSBUKCZJR_[]YLG@SJ\
T
[F    @VF\S_]\VpSD(
S+)NPJP
WIZ   CMRAR~ARPT\SZR((SWF    
[WRV_WYVYYVJSI&NNX@HR"BIIFEJLAR]BWRF\BUBJS\
LU&AI
SH]OTVYLU_PQTS:EINMP\POY UV\@RQtL\I~UJE
N]yMH    T
Y=J
LBQ\R[CKRBV[D@SO@X
!KIWyRXPVEN]E^HS#)@EyLOW]F
,UWUI_U[BN]_Z
SPZ+    AOILFX\^VQBGMV[TFEW^R=P,
C]I@FCMRF]D\Y@CNIyXSMAP
P
LJDP@OVBLV[LgNSOUVYP  OGS[L@C\CObOV_Z\US
PWIPLO^NfNX_C[[[XL_ES
NTVX
P
R SG  EJQW_@X\[MCZ\@=

X      AA:SV[LG@ZY^[]VS@CkHOMWPHD;HS
[E
UGLM>
NNPBHAO^J5
]ZqPDN^XCWUM
IEmFHAJL[QK\ZDDQK{YSJS
QOPS
ME@[[BOx_U[H^CUVS
N[\]HOK] LCX]V[@XACZDNS
NNQK
A
OYCIJM^O|YTRE^OJXI
JAP

BS]SA[NM`@[\\@CR\@SU@
P
AWIN!SKQ\A_vJDM@\\\@AHP*OOSV   LJUJDAJJXA]TPL~NOPMMH  T
JPX]BQRNLs@SN[\SOCfF
MVD[YS]YRY^SX]PACZI\FFVUTOnJ[A[CLG@SMJP AK
SZIGXP@CI[QXSI@SJEdP]IJFSX]U]MSN[ZEFLyINZHSCB\ENGJPTJJtNY^GWYAS

I[   PSZ,SH[MDJB@\F[PySWRGPCA){\\CV_JG@ZP]@SNT@  T\A$JNX_CJCU]C_^
SU\P&@V@XWU[[XL_E]SW@!SWI\F    FZ^DJBE~LV[“∞∂ESMFS[S[EZS\GG_WPFYI_ZEExZPSOO@VW@JXYJWED[S   pYPLCGS,S@Z\]FQQCV[TVSWK
P
S2SBQCZH^M[AAXU
'XCP   PON+FZ^RFURU\BGUFEOLK^PSOBJ>    EFXUW@PCFYQ[,T\PCKIAFE@X\BN%MUFKIR]MYW3OP
\Q^S\=/8 :ciY\[QPEX\[UGV]A_V\^LLS  SSEYOFJAKMSMH
Q[>OKVHPKSNLC_^AOVBHgXBT@SIR\P
K+AI
@I
A_\JTVXV\WYWQEzFPT\I[AKT@SrVM@BGQAEI\CH
JVbI\XCVEVVZZEUTS
NIPM(SZI
@I
SHXX_PJM_F@BRXB
EVUGHA
]SBIJPS\KOEt\JT^_ZE
I
V[G$TZS@I
DPRGZD\]\[UUKSO\HXA =CAEF_\^VI^W[BGUCS%IQAHSK$N
EVP\RHSJUASI_ZSOW]KS]L,SNYE}\@]C\]X@WXSX@H0
SgSV    LBQE\[\fBY\CSOVLL
OD[FZF\BObOG[]CS_\FEPW]PL   
]SFS}YRYSVCXA_IS
IG SZ:  SBMAA@PP[QT^T

SU@LKI@F
Y\MgGSUA[C_^E
K\  AC
KI_S}€±™CZD\@@I_ZS
S
M@HLcRY]
E
Q]EJ>TK    RBOMSKR$
LT@G(
Õ¥†EIYKPQ[XULfSSW^P AWIGI
CQURVN^@GX@DV?U@ÉÛ“&HI:EC[JT@[Z[QCZILK(L
O
S@I
FZ^T@Y]UMJKl_ES
M\\PP}EN@\COfXZXV\DYAEOVL6KSV   L_Q\VVEfV_]JS
OW]LCHS]SA[NMqVSTA[^PLy[SINIUK   AG
SV[LM{@F\@@FUU

SPWR3LTZL,SXUWE[YDUVAXQAE
OWOPCOlASFZ[^N[ZBQCNMQOHA
APEy\_SN[ZYY[JE
IKWWPCgIJI
CP]_[PDGZPM:TYWSKRL
NkO[JM%ZFC

@G
T
ICRT
    R9
S6II&]Sa[MXUFUXC]@YYB^IX[TxAGQˇŸ
```

Any ideas on what this could be ?.

Comment: Also, i delete the files but they are re-generated.

Comment: Clearly temp files created by a php program. Looks like photo uploads. You running some web server with some photo gallery software?

Comment: No, nothing like that. That's why i find this odd.

Comment: Then someone else is running a photo upload site on your server.  rename the files to .jpg, scan them with anti-virus or upload to virustotal, then view them as a non root user.  Use exiv2 to extract the exif data.

Answer (score 0):

These are PHP upload temporary files. They are left in temporary directory when not handled (moved) by an application, when moving fails due to permission problems, etc. Enable logging (check *error_reporting*, *error_log* and *log_errors*), preferably to a single file or *syslog*, to find which scripts throw errors related to ie. *move_uploaded_file()* function.

For security reasons, it is recommended (amongst others) to set a separate *upload_tmp_dir* and *open_basedir* for every PHP application in the system. This will prevent PHP from messing with the global temporary dir, and will also clearly indicate what app/user leaves unhandled upload files. Enabling file uploads only for the webapps that really need them will also improve security and control over your system.